# I would like know whether the other sentences are also right as the sentence A

Tags: conditional-constructions, tense-agreement

I am not a native English speaker and would like to ask you a question.
I wonder whether the sentence B, C are also okay in addition to the sentence A.

Sentence A.

> "**Can** I move to a rural area and grow crops if I **am** able to make good money by farming?"

Sentence B.

> "**Can** I move to a rural area and grow crops if I **was** able to make good money by farming?"

Sentence C.

> "**Could** I move to a rural area and grow crops if I **was** able to make good money by farming?"

Comment: *"....if I **were**"*....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A is fine.

C is almost OK but "I was" needs to be "I were" (subjunctive)

B is wrong because the tense of "Can I move" doesn't agree with the tense of "I was able" (and, as per C, "I was" needs to be "I were")

Comment: tkp, but I have one more thing to ask about this post.